# Is it right that "import pkg.module" is equivalent "import module" in pkg/__init.py__ in 2.7 but not in 3.5?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have the following files:

```
pkg/__init_.py
pkg/module.py
```

Now, in `pkg/__init__.py`, how do I import `module`?

Is it

```
import pkg.module
```

or

```
import module
```

?

**Is it right, that in Python 2.7 both methods work, while Python 3.x requires the first one?**

Comment: It is  `import module`. I don't get why you should need the absolute dirctory hieracy path, at least in python3 it is definitely not needed

Comment: @h_e_u_r_e_k_a It is not `import module`. It doesn't work in Python 3! And may be ambiguous in Python 2, that's why this isn't possible in Python 3 anymore. Think of a module called module in the standard library, or any other import path. To which does `import module` refer then?

Comment: @BlackJack: So that means my assumption is "right" then? Could you put it in a short answer? (I can do it as well.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumptions are basically right.

The second way may not work in Python 2.7 if there is a module named `module` in the module search path (`sys.path`) before the one you actually want to import.  That's why Python 3 switched to absolute imports, to make importing safer and more predictable.

It is possible to change the Python 2.7 import to work linke Python 3 with `from __future__ import absolute_import` at the top of the module.

Both Python versions also allow an explicit relative import within packages:

```
from . import module
```